# Writing NDEF in java with acr122

Tags: java, c#, nfc

I could to read and write text on smartcards (mifare 1k) with the acr122u device using the library javax.smartcardio now the problem is that I need to write and read with NDEF format but java do not give that library, only is available on android, how can write the blocks like NDEF plain text? or exist a library for java that implement NDEF?

that is for my title project and I do not found solutions, I have thought in C# too, ther is a way to write NDEF with acr122u in that languaje?

Comment: You  can write NFC tags using C# and Java, but the out of the box support is for Android and Windows Phone, you probably need to find right library to make it work with this acr...

Answer (score 0):

It's not good place to ask about library.

But here a library https://github.com/grundid/nfctools

A simple search in goolge "java ndef library" give you result.

Comment: I have tried this library but I did not get done work it, it works with maven and always appear a error message that say:  com.mycompany:NFCTEST:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.nfctools:nfctools-ndef:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,.... etc. Can I use only a jar library of this project (nfctools) without use maven?

Comment: @ZanackSayks jar is enable here : http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/nfctools/nfctools-api/1.0.M8/nfctools-api-1.0.M8.jar